# Is there a method to check if a container needs scrollbars?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a method to check if a container needs scrollbars possibly without adding an object to the container?

Alternatively is there a method to tell if scaled content extends past it's container?

**Update:**
It looks like there is a element.scrollTopMax and element.scrollLeftMax.
That might be non zero after an element is larger than the container.

Comment: element.scrollHeight > parentElement.scrollHeight

Comment: you can check for overflow if `element.scrollHeight > element.offsetHeight`. What's the Purpose for this? Can you paint a bigger picture?

Comment: @Shashank my parentElement may contain more this just this one Element.

Comment: @paulie_D Please reopen. This is not the same question.

Answer (score 1):

if you use `overflow:auto` in the css and the scroll bar will automatically add to the container if the content goes beyond the maximum height.

Comment: That will show scrollbars but I want to know if scrollbars are needed.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with the scrollbar because i think you can set the max-height value to the css